# List all Running Applications Foreground and Background

Tags: android

I am trying to list all the applications running in the foreground and background in my service. The current that I see, seems to return only the name of my application, while the other services are not listed. It seems because of some changes in API > 21. My target API is 22. Can somebody help me with the code to list all the applications name and PID

My current code is

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()

    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfoList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfoList) {
        Log.d("MyService", "...." + processInfo.processName );
    }
```

I have also tried the `getAppTasks()` too, but it also returns same thing.

Comment: That is no longer practical on modern versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()

            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfoList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfoList) {
                Log.d("MyService", "...." + processInfo.processName);
            }
        } else {
            UsageStatsManager usage = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> stats = usage.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);
            if (stats != null) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> runningTask = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                    runningTask.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
            }
        }
```

and in manifest add this line

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

and in oncreate of activity

```
if (hasPermissionToReadNetworkHistory()) {
            // do your stuff here

        }
```

And finally the method here

```
private boolean hasPermissionToReadNetworkHistory() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            return true;
        }
        final AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
        if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
            return true;
        }
        appOps.startWatchingMode(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                new AppOpsManager.OnOpChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    public void onOpChanged(String op, String packageName) {
                        int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                                android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
                        if (mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        appOps.stopWatchingMode(this);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ChildMainActivity.this, ChildMainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        requestReadNetworkHistoryAccess();
        return false;
    }
```